# about sql query php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to search the terminal whose active session is more than 100, the table I use is terminal_server_log, because there are a lot of logs for each terminal, I have to make sure the "timestamp" is the latest one. I have tried two ways to search. Note that for every terminal, the latest timestamp is not the same.

```
$termquery=mysql_query("select distinct(terminal) from
    terminal_server_log where activesession > 100
    group by terminal order by timestamp limit 1");
while($termres=mysql_fetch_array($termquery)){
        $terms=$termres["terminal"];

    array_push($result, array(
          "terminal" => array(
                "type" => "resource",
                "searchvector" => "/tsmon-dev/api/terminal.php?username=$terms",
                "displayvalue" => $terms
                 )
           )
     );
}

echo (json_encode($result));
```

However, it does not work. What is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Please note that the `mysql_` constructor is [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and is outright [**removed in PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), ensuring that you also use [**parameterised queries**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent SQL injection :)

Comment: you need to count how many terminal from terminal_server_log then order them descending... is that what you want? or you want the terminal that has the latest entry first?

Comment: "active sessions" is that a field in table terminal_server_log ?

Comment: As it stands, this question is impossible to answer. You've not told us about  the schema nor how it is populated and "does not work" is not a useful diagnostic of what is happening when you run the code.

Comment: Yes, active session" is a field. The field you need is "active session", "terminal", "timestamp". Actually I need "terminal" whose active session is more than 100, but in the log, there are many records, so i need the max(timestamp) for each terminal. However, for different terminals, the max(timestamp) are also different.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all the terminals with `activesession > 100`, then there is no sense in using `limit 1`

`select terminal, max(timestamp) from terminal_server_log where activesession > 100 group by terminal`

It will return pairs [terminal, timestamp] with terminals only with activesession>100 and where timestamp for every record will be latest.

If you want to get ONE terminal with activesession>100 with latest record, query will be:

`select terminal from terminal_server_log where activesession > 100 order by timestamp desc limit 1`

And yes,

> please note that the mysql_ constructor is deprecated as of PHP 5.5
>   //Obsidian Age advised in comments.

**UPDATED**

> Actually I only want to know the current situation: which terminal's
>   active session is more than 100. I mean, for each terminal, there are
>   a lot of records, if the latest record for this terminal's active
>   session is more than 100, then i choose it

```
SELECT  a.terminal
FROM    terminal_server_log a
inner join
        (
            SELECT  terminal, MAX(timestamp) timestamp
            FROM    terminal_server_log
            group by terminal
        ) b on (b.terminal=a.terminal and a.timestamp=b.timestamp)
WHERE a.activesession>100
```

Comment: Thanks, but as i expected, the answer will return all the logs whose active session is more than 100, not the latest one.

Comment: Second query it for latest one

Comment: I tried in MySQL, the result is the same as the first one. Output is a terminal whose active session once is more than 100 in 2016, a very old record.

Comment: It doesn't make sense: second query gets all terminals with activesession>100, sorts them by timestamp starting with newest one and gives you first record in list. The case may be that you have timestamp as char/varchar/text instead of date/datetime/time/int. Then you have huge trouble and need to convert it either before query or during query

Comment: Actually I only want to know the current situation: which terminal's active session is more than 100. I mean, for each terminal, there are a lot of records, if the latest record for this terminal's active session is more than 100, then i choose it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150648/discussion-between-ixcray-and-user8348955).

Comment: Yes, you are right. Must use two tables and inner join. Thanks.